# set of all $a$ such that the sequence $\{n^2 a^n\}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was trying to find the set of all $a$ such that the sequence $\{n^2 a^n\}_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ is convergent!

If $a = 0$ its convergent!

if $a = 1$ then its not!

if $a = -1$ then its not!

if $a = 2$ then its not

if $a =-2$ its not

if $a = 0.5$ then it is convergent as $n^2 < 2^n \forall n \geq 5$, and thus the sequence $\{\frac{n^2}{2^n}\}$ tends to zero and hence converges?

So guess is $a \in (-1,1)$ then the sequence $\{n^2 a^n\}$ is convergent!

Any rigorous or other technique we can apply to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sequence converges then there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $|n^2a^n|<M$ so $|a^n|=|a|^n<Mn^{-2}$ or $|a|<M^{\frac 1n}n^{-\frac 2n} \to 1$.

Comment: We have  a sequence though!

Comment: Yes, but if a sequence converges, then for all $n$ larger than some number, this sequence is bounded.

Comment: @BAYMAX Precision: strict inequality is not conserved in the limit process, so we get $|a|\le 1$ and then we can discard $a=\pm 1$ a posteriori. This is somehow hidden in this one liner.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, for $|a| \geq 1$, $|n^2a^n| \geq |n^2|$, so it is unbounded and hence cannot converge.

For $|a| < 1$, note that $n^2a^n \to 0$. The best way to prove this would be to note that the ratio of consecutive terms of this sequence converges to $a$ as $n \to \infty$.

Now, this means that if $b_n = n^2a^n$, then for some $N \in \mathbb N$ we have $n > N \implies b_{n+1} < (\frac{1+a}{2}) b_n$ (I could take any number between $1$ and $a$, but I just took the average). You can see that now $b_n \to 0$, since $0 \leq b_{n+k} \leq (\frac{1+a}2)^k b_n$ for $n > N$, and one can apply the squeeze theorem. So $b_{N+n} \to 0$, and hence $b_n \to 0$.